# Scipy minimize result is higher than with initial guess values

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I am trying to estimate the parameters of the models jointly using nonlinear least squares, minimizing the sum of squared differences between the actual and model based estimates. However the resulting value is higher than the SSE with my guessed values. Guessed values SSE is 2,951,687, optimized parameters SSE is 4,281,096.

versions: python 3.7.6, numpy 1.19.2, scipy 1.5.2

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from scipy.optimize import minimize
    
    ###################### importing the excel file ######################
    df = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
    
    ###################### Setting up variables and arrays ######################
    a = df.loc[:,'C(ADD)'].values #measured added customers
    l = df.loc[:,'C(Loss)'].values #measured lost customers
    m = df.loc[:,'m'].values #number of months
    mkt = df.loc[:,'Marketing Expense'].values #maketing dollars     in each month
    e = 5596 #end measured value, Calculated from the cac/total marketing spend over the time period
    n = len(df) #creates a variable of the length of the dataframe
    
    ###################### Defining equations ######################
    
    g0 = np.zeros(n) #guess values
    g0[0] = 0.0001
    g0[1] = 0.006
    g0[2] = 96755.00
    g0[3] = 1.7
    g0[4] = 0.6
    g0[5] = 0.1
    g0[6] = 0.006
    g0[7] = 1.7
    g0[8] = 0.6
    
    def addhat(g): #Add predict values
        pNT = g[0]
        r = g[1]
        alpha = g[2]
        c = g[3]
        Bm = g[4]
        ah = np.empty(len(df)) #an empty array for the add hat values
        b = np.empty(n) #an empty array for the B(m,m') values
    
        b[0] = np.exp(np.log(mkt[0])*Bm)
        ah[0] = 400000*((1-pNT) * (1 - (alpha/(alpha + b[0]))**r))
    
        for i in range(1, n):
            b[i] = b[i-1] + (m[i]**c - m[i-1]**c)*np.exp(np.log(mkt[i])*Bm)
            ah[i] = 400000*((1-pNT) * (1 - (alpha/(alpha + (b[i])))**r))
        return ah
    
    print('add pred values: ' + str(addhat(g0)))
    
    def rethat(g): #Retention percentage
        rr = g[5]
        alphar = g[6]
        cr = g[7]
        Bmr = g[8]
    
        k = np.empty(n) #an empty array for exponent section of the formula
        w = np.empty(n) #an empty array for the retention values
    
        #The value of b(t)r when i = 0
        k[0] = np.exp(np.log(mkt[0])*Bmr)
    
        w[0] = 1 - (alphar/(alphar + k[0]))**rr
    
        # the value of B(t) for all other values of q
        for i in range(1, n):
            k[i] = k[i-1] + (m[i]**cr - m[i-1]**cr)*np.exp(np.log(mkt[i])*Bmr)
            w[i] = 1 - (alphar/(alphar + (k[i])))**rr
        return w
    
    def endpred(g): #predicting the end hat values
        eh = np.empty(n) #an empty array for the end hat values
    
        eh[0] = 213
        for i in range(1, n):
            eh[i] = (eh[i-1] * rethat(g)[i]) + addhat(g)[i]
        return eh
        
    endhat = sum(endpred(g0))
    
    def losshat(g):
        lh = np.empty(n) #an empty array for the loss hat values
    
        lh[0] = 0
        for i in range(1, n):
            lh[i] = endpred(g)[i-1] - (endpred(g)[i] - addhat(g)[i])
        return lh
    
    ###################### Sum of square errors ######################
    
    def objective(g):
        sse = sum((addhat(g)-a)**2 + (losshat(g)-l)**2) + (endhat-e)**2
        return sse
    print("SSE Initial: " + str(objective(g0)))
    ###################### Constraints ######################
    def constraint1(g): #c is greater than 1
        return g[3] - 1
    
    def constraint2(g): #cr is greater than 1
        return g[7] - 1
    
    def constraint3(g): #pNT is greater than 0
        return g[0]
    
    con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
    con2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint2}
    con3 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint3}
    cons = [con1, con2, con3]
    
    ###################### Optimize ######################
    s = minimize(objective, g0, method='SLSQP', constraints = cons)
    g = s.x
    
    print(g)
    print("SSE Final: " + str(objective(g)))
```

The resulting SSE value is 4,281,096.9 with the values being:
`3.48133574e+02, 6.84452015e+02, 9.67550032e+04, 2.22008198e+00, -3.28153006e+03, -1.91454144e+02, 2.20947909e+02, 1.70207912e+00, -1.24649708e+01`

The initial guess values I have used are quite close to the actual result values (I'm checking my code with a problem I know the result to). The results should be `0.0001001361, 0.006035783, 96,755.64542, 1.78204741, 0.636357403, 0.152, 0.0065432195, 1.73490796, 0.62625507` which have a SSE of 912,278.

[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1srMQu-hGC65ZcyRXHy1xWe6dB9JGOWr1/view?usp=sharing) to the `data2.csv`.

Thanks again for your help

Comment: When I run it, I get overflow error messages: 'RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp' etc. Do you encounter the same problem?

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem Mr. T. I don't encounter any errors when running my code, its terminates successfully. I am running it in Visual Basic using jupyter notebook with python 3.7.6. But I will try and run it in google colab to see if I can replicate your error

Comment: I ran it in google collab, again I didn't have any errors. I'm not sure what might be going on. Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: I tried it in Eclipse/PyDev on Linux and Win10, both generate the same error message. Different Python 3.x versions but I upgraded recently scipy/numpy on both, so maybe you use other versions of these packages that don't explicitly mention the overflow? [Error message](https://imgur.com/a/fYPuxnI)

Comment: Thanks for your continued help Mr. T. I updated scipy (1.5.2) and numpy (1.19.2) and ran it in jypter notebook, not through visual studio and I'm now getting the same error. Obviously not the best result, but it now gives me something to work with so that's great

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the same variable `l` for 2 different purposes.
It is first initialized with a fixed value from the CSV file, but also used as an internal variable in function `rethat`. And is also used in the objective function - which means that every time you optimize, you also change the objective function.
That does not look good...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I have updated the code, but I am unfortunately still getting a similar result